# How to color rows based on a check box - Open Office

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice

How do you color the background of a cell based on a check box?
More to the point, I have created a check box that is in a cell. I want that cell to be green when the check box is checked and red when it's not.

Comment: did you try like this  https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#Syntax_3

Comment: don't know how to implement it in conditional formating

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your checkbox is in cell `A1` and if checked it returns a value of true. Then the logical functions looks like this

```
=IF(A1 = "true" ;0;1)
```

explained

```
=IF(A1 = "true" ; "then this value" ; "else this other value")
```

Problem was that the conditional does not work on text or string values that's why we go with this example:

```
=IF(A1 = "true" ;0;1)
```

Now if we follow this link: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/201/dynamic-cell-background-color/ it says to select all cells you want

> - Select te range to format. Menue Format->Conditinal Formatting >Conditinal Formatting. In the wndow click Add, some prefilled drop-down boxes appear:
> - Select Top left: "All Cells" Center "Color Scale (2 Entries)",

and then we do not set min/max we check the value like: [image]